# В чем разница foreach и std::for_each в с++?

Tags: c++

Я новичок в C++

Читаю пример и наткрулся на такую конструкцию `std::for_each` и не понял, зачем она нужна когда есть стандартный for(val v : array)?

Протестировал на время выполнения

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>


#include <chrono>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void testDeleteIt() {
    std::vector<int> workers;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
        workers.push_back(i);
    }

    int count = 0;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int &i : workers) {
        count += i;
    }

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "HERE", "HERE ::: %s", std::to_string(count).c_str());
    count = 0;

    long long int duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - t1).count();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TIME1", "TIME 1::: %s", std::to_string(duration).c_str());

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();


    std::for_each(workers.begin(), workers.end(), [&count](int &i) -> void {
        count += i;
    });

    count = 0;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "HERE", "HERE ::: %s", std::to_string(count).c_str());

    duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - t2).count();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "TIME2", "TIME 2 ::: %s", std::to_string(duration).c_str());
}
```

И получилось, что стандартный цикл выполныется почти в 2 раза быстрее

```
TIME 1::: 10102
TIME 2 ::: 18459
```

И плюс в `std::for_each` еще и заморочки с лямбдой

Так в чем тогда его преимущество?

Comment: *"стандартный цикл выполныется почти в 3 раза быстрее"* - заявленное поведение не воспроизводится. [Современные компиляторы вполне себе генерируют сходный код для обоих вариантов итерации](https://godbolt.org/z/zx_V9z). Ну и вообще приведенный пример кода не является самодостаточным и даже не собирается.

Comment: @VTT добавил include. Почему не воспроизводиться? А какие у вас значения тогда получаются?

Comment: Я же привел ссылку - код генерируется одинаковый, соответственно и время выполнения тоже будет одинаковое. `#include <android/log.h>` не является стандартным файлом, используемая платформа и настройки компилятора у вас в вопросе не указаны. Еще я сильно подозреваю, что замеры времени производились при запуске отладочной версии.

Comment: А как вы компилируете?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Читаю пример и наткнулся на такую конструкцию std::for_each и не понял, зачем она нужна когда есть стандартный for(val v : array)?

Все просто - `std::for_each` появился как минимум на 10 лет раньше. Поэтому, да, теперь есть стандартный for. Но Вы не единственный, кто [задается таким вопросом](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/03/30/is-stdfor_each-obsolete/).

Но есть несколько особенностей. `std::for_each` умеет несколько дополнительных возможностей.

- `std::for_each` умеет работать с произвольным диапазоном, заданный двумя итераторами. Стандартный for умеет только begin-end.
- `std::for_each` можно перегрузить для своего типа и сделать цикл "быстрее" - потому что функция будет знать внутренности вашего типа.
- А ещё в 17 стандарт подвезли `execution_policy`. А это значит, что легким движением можно сделать `for_each` "многопоточным" и контейнер будет обрабатываться значительно быстрее.

В ответе вы тестируете суммирование. Тогда используйте `std::accumulate`. У меня есть подозрение, что в первом случае компилятор разобрался, что Вы именно суммируете и просто заменил на формулу "суммы ряда". Clang так точно умеет. В этом случае сравнивать производительность двух циклов немного некорректно.

Comment: Да, я забыл указать все это. Ваш ответ лучший

Comment: Вы не могли бы рассказать подробнее про перегрузку для своего типа? Или речь идёт об ADL: `using std::for_each; for_each(mybegin, myend, myf)`?

Comment: здесь https://cukic.co/2018/04/03/more-to-std-for-each-than-meets-the-eye/

Answer (score 7):

Вообще то стандартные алгоритмы(и не только) существуют для того, чтобы каждый раз не написать в ручную код, который уже написан в  лучшем виде.
Если утверждать, что  `std::for_each` не нужен, то с таким успехом можно утверждать, что ни один стандартный алгоритм не нужен. Ведь всегда можно написать самому и алгоритм и класс, заменяющий стандартный... Кроме того  `std::for_each` возвращает свой аргумент функтор, в котором может хранится важная информация. Написать в ручную то же самое можно, но часто проще и надежнее(во избежании ошибок) использовать именно стандартный алгоритм. В указанном вами конкретном  примере, думаю уместнее обходиться без него.

p.s. кроме того     For-цикл по коллекции появился позже, чем   этот алгоритм. И еще... пример, где можно работать с конкретным диапазоном, без использования `std::for_each`

```
int m[6] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 11};
for (int& i : m) {
    static size_t k = 0;
    if (k && k <= 3)
        ++i;
    ++k;
}
```

По этому примеру очевидно, что если последовательность будет состоять из `10000` элементов, а нам нужно обрабатывать какой то маленький диапазон , то все равно нужно пройтись по всем и еще каждый раз проверять условие, что намного дороже чем в `std::for_each` передать именно этот диапазон, и таким образом рассмотреть только этот диапазон

Comment: Минусовщикам прошу указать на ошибку

Comment: Тут минусятор просто завёлся, периодически тупо минусит всё подряд. Не думаю, что он вообще читал ответ/вопрос.

Comment: думаю, что нас минусатор - грамманаци. В Вашем ответе, @ARHovsepyan , как минимум дважды встречается "альгоритм".

Comment: @KoVadim , :))))

Comment: Я не утверждал, что стандартный метод не нужен, просто спросил в чем его польза если есть метод который делает тоже самое но проще и быстрее... Но теперь понятно что и как

Comment: А я и не говорил, что вы утверждали, а сказал, если... Извените, если я  не так выражаюсь, как надобы

Comment: ну почему "альгоритм"? или правила русского языка были изменены?